# Why filter-bank energies coefficients are same through the frame?

Tags: mfcc, dct, c++, filter-bank

I am trying to implement MFCC's from scratch in C++. In each frame, I am processing real-valued data to construct MFCC vectors. Although I think that my implementation is correct, the testing result is very interesting for me. Here is how I implement the MFCC step by step, then the confusing things becomes.

This is how I implemented the filters. I am interested in signal frequencies as 200 Hz as min and 800 Hz as max. I am dealing with only one frame now.(No loop on frames)

```cpp
std::vector<double> MFCC(NUM_MFCSS);
std::vector<std::vector<double>> filters(
    NUM_FILTERS, std::vector<double>(FFT_SIZE / 2 + 1));
double mel_min = 2595 * log10(1 + (200 / 700));
double mel_max = 2595 * log10(1 + (800 / 700));
double mel_spacing = (mel_max - mel_min) / (NUM_FILTERS + 1);
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_FILTERS; i++) {
  double mel_center = mel_min + mel_spacing * (i + 1);
  double f_min = 700 * (pow(10, mel_center / 2595) - 1);
  double f_max = 700 * (pow(10, (mel_center + mel_spacing) / 2595) - 1);
  double f_spacing = (f_max - f_min) / FFT_SIZE;
  for (int j = 0; j < FFT_SIZE / 2 + 1; j++) {
    double f = f_min + f_spacing * j;
    double mel = 2595 * log10(1 + (f / 700));
    if (mel < mel_center - mel_spacing / 2) {
      filters[i][j] = (mel - (mel_center - mel_spacing)) / (mel_spacing / 2);
    } else if (mel > mel_center + mel_spacing / 2) {
      filters[i][j] = ((mel_center + mel_spacing) - mel) / (mel_spacing / 2);
    } else {
      filters[i][j] = 1;
    }
  }
}
```

Converting it to the mel-scale and appropriate triangular filters are constructed.

Then I apply Hanning Window and FFT. I checked FFT works correctly.
Then I tried to get filter-bank energies with dot-product of filters and fft's as follows:

```
std::vector<double> energies(NUM_FILTERS, 0);
for (int j = 0; j < NUM_FILTERS; j++) {
  for (int k = 0; k < (FFT_SIZE / 2) + 1; k++) {
    energies[j] +=
        filters[j][k] * (fft[k][0] * fft[k][0] + fft[k][1] * fft[k][1]);
  }
}
```

Once I applied the log of energies and DCT operation, I obtained the MFCC coefficients.

```
for (int j = 1; j < NUM_MFCSS + 1; j++) {
  double sum = 0;
  for (int k = 0; k < NUM_FILTERS; k++) {
    sum += log10(energies[k]) * std::cos(M_PI * j * (k - 0.5) / NUM_FILTERS);
  }
  MFCC[j] = sum;
}
```

My test signal is simply sinusoid of the frequencies in the range [200 Hz,800 Hz].

I applied hoop size to see the other frames energy and MFCC coefficients. What I observe are the following

1. Filter-bank energies are constant for every index.
2. MFCC coefficients are 0 in odd indexes, and in even indexes they are strictly decreasing. I could not interpret this two things. Why they are the case? Did you see any implementational/logical mistakes that I wrote?